# Writing multi-stream MP4 file with Gstreamer

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gstreamer

My Gstreamer 1.20 application is writing two H.264 video streams and one Opus audio stream to a MP4 file. The relevant parts of the pipeline looks as follows:

Video encoder (this part is present twice):

```
queue max-size-time=100000000 leaky=downstream ! x264enc bitrate=1500 speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency key-int-max=15 ! video/x-h264,profile=constrained-baseline,stream-format=avc ! queue ! mux.
```

Audio encoder:

```
queue max-size-time=100000000 leaky=downstream ! opusenc bitrate-type=vbr inband-fec=true ! queue ! opusparse ! mux.
```

Muxer and filesink:

```
mp4mux name=mux fragment-duration=1000 latency=100000000 ! filesink sync=true location=out.mp4
```

The result is an MP4 file which I can play just fine in Totem on Ubuntu, and even switch between video streams using "Switch angles".

However, none of the following work:

- play it in VLC (plays a few seconds, then freezes)
- do anything with FFMPEG, e.g. split the streams (results are garbage)
- seek in the video (even in Totem)

In all cases, I get some messages about "Invalid NAL unit size" and/or "non-monotonous DTS". So what would I need to do to my output pipeline to get a "compliant" MP4 file?

---

Note: I can "fix" the resulting file by using GStreamer with `qtdemux` to split it into two raw H.264 files and a WAV file, and then use `ffmpeg` to re-encode it into MP4 with an MP3 audio track. But I'd rather have a workable MP4 file right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Your pipeline may lack video information from caps</s>. You may check with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! x264enc bitrate=1500 speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency key-int-max=15 insert-vui=1 ! video/x-h264,profile=constrained-baseline,stream-format=avc ! queue ! mux. \
 videotestsrc pattern=ball ! video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! x264enc bitrate=1500 speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency key-int-max=15 insert-vui=1 ! video/x-h264,profile=constrained-baseline,stream-format=avc ! queue ! mux. \
 audiotestsrc ! audioresample ! voaacenc ! queue ! mux. \
 qtmux name=mux fragment-duration=1000 ! queue ! filesink sync=true location=out.mp4

# Or try mkv for opus:
gst-launch-1.0 \
 videotestsrc ! queue ! x264enc bitrate=1500 speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency key-int-max=15 ! video/x-h264,profile=constrained-baseline,stream-format=avc ! queue ! mux. \
 videotestsrc pattern=ball ! queue ! x264enc bitrate=1500 speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency key-int-max=15 ! video/x-h264,profile=constrained-baseline,stream-format=avc ! queue ! mux. \
 audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! opusenc ! queue ! mux.  \
 matroskamux name=mux ! queue ! filesink sync=true location=out.mkv
```

Once recorded, you should be able to see the streams:

```
# stream 0
ffplay -autoexit out.mp4

# stream 1
ffplay -autoexit out.mp4 -vst v:1
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the magic bit that differs is the `insert-vui=1` parameter for `x264enc`, correct? I'll test that right away.

Comment: No, I think that main point is having caps specifying a video format.

Comment: Seems I replied a bit too fast... Now checking further, as shown in my edit it works without caps...maybe it is jsut a container issue, as it seems working fine with opus in mkv container or voaac with qtmux.

Comment: Good point. I also noticed you have a queue between muxer and filesink, that may have some influence in the usecase with live sources (which is my primary one). So what I'll try next is a) switch to MKV and b) add another queue.

Comment: The queue in the filesink pipeline may not be mandatory, it may also depends on your gstreamer version, but it shouldn't harm to have it especially with recent gst versions. Let us know if this works as a starting point and where it doesn't work any longer. About caps, videotestsrc may provide more than your appsrc, so you may also check this...my initial post was about ffmpeg not finding video format that went to work after setting caps to correct video.

Comment: In the end, your post did point me into the right direction: I just had to switch from `qtmux`/`mp4mux` to `matroskamux offset-to-zero=true` and the resulting MKV file can be played and is seekable. Good enough.